# Parse JSON from array and objects to HTML table

Tags: html, json

I have a MySQL db having columns "Name" "Service" "Cost" the output in JSON gives me like this:

```
"report": [{
        "Name": "John",
        "Service": "Hands",
        "Cost": "200"
    }]
}
```

I want to be able to convert this to a html table. I have tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var json = url;
    var tr;
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        tr = $('<tr/>');
        tr.append("<td>" + report.json[i].Name + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + report.json[i].Service + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + report.json[i].Cost + "</td>");
        $('table').append(tr);
    }
});
```

But is not working, simply because i'm don't exactly know what I'm doing :)

Can someone help me?
Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by json=url? You want to get the json from a URL with ajax? then you should use `$.ajax` or `$.get`. Then report would be a subproperty of json, not the other way around and you would have to enumerate for json.report.length. Also, $('table') adds the table rows to all the tables in the page; you should probably use an id ($('#myTable) )

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes it is from a url, but I don't know exactly how to do the way you explained. Can you give me a whole example?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() { //equivalent to $(document).ready(...
 $.getJSON(url,function(data) {
   var report=data.report;
   // your code here
 });
});
```

Read about [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) and [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).